# Is there a way to implement the rate limit to express.js?

Tags: express

What is the best way to implement rate limits per IP into Node.js Express API App?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// rate limiting here?
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Have you tried the first, second or third Google hits for "rate limit express.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use NODE package "Express Rate Limit".

`npm install express-rate-limit`

then add this in your Express.js App:

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
 
const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100
});
 
// only apply to requests that begin with /test/
app.use("/test/", apiLimiter);
```

[read more - docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)

Comment: Why do you think this is the "best way to implement rate limits" as was asked in the question?